# Implementing Google Pay in Android application using BlueSnap

Tags: java, android, google-pay, bluesnap

I want to implement Google pay in my android application and I want `BlueSnap` as `Google Pay` processor. I have implemented `Google Pay` in may app and have also created `BlueSnap` sandbox account. When I enter my live card details i receive this toast **Successfully received payment data**. I have also written **bluesnap** in gateway and sandbox merchant id in `GatewayMerchantId`. Now I am stuck, can someone help me out on how to send this payment data to `BlueSnap` and get payment confirmation from `BlueSnap` so that my payment would show on `BlueSnap` sandbox dashboard.

Thank you.

I have uploaded my `handlePaymentSuccess()` code where I am receiving toast and `gatewatTokenization()` method where I have written gateway and merchantId. If you need more code, I can upload it.

```
private void handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentData paymentData) {

        String paymentInformation = paymentData.toJson();

        // Token will be null if PaymentDataRequest was not constructed using fromJson(String).
        if (paymentInformation == null) {
            return;
        }
        JSONObject paymentMethodData;

        try {

            paymentMethodData = new JSONObject(paymentInformation).getJSONObject("paymentMethodData");
            // If the gateway is set to "example", no payment information is returned - instead, the
            // token will only consist of "examplePaymentMethodToken".
            if (paymentMethodData
                    .getJSONObject("tokenizationData")
                    .getString("type")
                    .equals("PAYMENT_GATEWAY")
                    && paymentMethodData
                    .getJSONObject("tokenizationData")
                    .getString("token")
                    .equals("examplePaymentMethodToken")) {
                android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog =
                        new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                .setTitle("Warning")
                                .setMessage(
                                        "Gateway name set to \"example\" - please modify "
                                                + "Constants.java and replace it with your own gateway.")
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                                .create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

            String billingName =
                    paymentMethodData.getJSONObject("info").getJSONObject("billingAddress").getString("name");

            JSONObject testing =
                    paymentMethodData.getJSONObject("info");

            JSONObject testingNew =
                    paymentMethodData;

            try {
                String paymentToken = createBlsTokenFromGooglePayPaymentData(paymentData);
                //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(paymentToken), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("BillingName", billingName);
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.payments_show_name, billingName), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(testing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            // Logging token string.
            Log.d("GooglePaymentToken", paymentMethodData.getJSONObject("tokenizationData").getString("token"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("handlePaymentSuccess", "Error: " + e.toString());
            return;
        }
    }
```

```
private static JSONObject getGatewayTokenizationSpecification() throws JSONException {
    return new JSONObject(){{
      put("type", "PAYMENT_GATEWAY");
      put("parameters", new JSONObject(){{
        put("gateway", "bluesnap");
        put("gatewayMerchantId", "######");//i've hidden MerchantId
        }
      });
    }};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [BlueSnap's documentation](https://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/google-pay#section-step-3-create-a-google-pay-wallet-token):

> This `paymentToken` should be sent to the BlueSnap API, which is detailed in the [Processing Transactions](https://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/google-pay#section-processing-transactions) section.

I think the relevant piece is to issue a HTTP POST to BlueSnap with the `paymentToken` that you received as part of `createBlsTokenFromGooglePayPaymentData`:

> ```sh
> curl -v -X POST https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/transactions \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> -H 'Accept: application/json' \ 
> -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' \
> -d '
> {
>     "cardTransactionType": "AUTH_CAPTURE",
>     "softDescriptor": "DescTest",
>     "amount": 11.00,
>     "currency": "USD",
>     "wallet": {
>       "walletType": "GOOGLE_PAY",
>       "encodedPaymentToken": "ImRhdGEiOiJuY1AvRitIUy8zeG5bXhCMFd"
>     }
> }
> ```

Where `paymentToken` is assigned to the value of `encodedPaymentToken`.